# textfield : cannot copy and paste

Tags: applescript, copy-paste

I have a simple AppleScript app on Xcode 
The issue is that I cannot copy and paste in all textfields.

Right click / Past work but CMD+ V is not available

I'm not sure how can I change that for an AppleScript based app.

Comment: Please describe the specific problem you're experiencing using a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thinking on it, its probably because I get rid at edit in the menu bar.....

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I get rid of the edit menu, 
Add the edit menu back fixed the issue.